In key=joserfc.jwk.RSAKey.import_key(string) can I cache (key,string) and avoid calling import_key? (Python)
I've some Python pytests that call (indirectly)
key = joserfc.jwk.RSAKey.import_key(string).
This is pretty slow so I'm hoping there is a way I can save the (string,key) combination in a cache, and then use that to stub the call.
I've tried saving key using pickle, but I get
TypeError: cannot pickle 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust.openssl.rsa.RSAPrivateKey' object

You can't use pickle, but you can use the serialization methods of the cryptography package. See https://cryptography.io/en/stable/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#key-loading and https://cryptography.io/en/stable/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#key-serialization.
